# Making callback inside paypal.payment.get method

Tags: javascript, node.js, paypal, callback

I'm trying to get 2 values from a response of paypal's get method, but whenever I try to callback, it gets error "callback is not a function".

I've no idea what's wrong, I've tried making the callback outside the get function but it's return undefined. Where and how am i supposed to do it? Console logs, show me the right information but I odn't know how to return it.

I'm using async library and this is one of the functions in the waterfall.

```
function payment_info(paypalT, callback){

var paid;
var state; 

paypal.configure({
  'mode': 'sandbox', //sandbox or live
  'client_id': 'xxx',
  'client_secret': 'xxx'
});

paypal.payment.get(paypalT, function (error, payment) {
if (error) {
    console.log(error);
    throw error;
} else {
    console.log("Get Payment Response");
    console.log(JSON.stringify(payment));

    paid = payment.transactions[0].amount.total;
    state = payment.state;

    console.log("inside paypal method" + paid + state);


  callback(null, paid, state);

}

});

};
```

And this is where I call the function, after my first function makes callback correctly.

```
exports.verifyPayment = function(token, id_establecimiento, paypalT, cantidad, comision, fecha, orden, entrega, callback) { 
async.waterfall([
async.apply(getNombrePrecio, paypalT, orden),
payment_info,
checkPayment, //this is where I want to get paid and state values but can't callback from payment_info
savePedido
  ], function(err, results){
if(err){
  console.log(err);
  callback({"failure": "something wrong happened"});
}

callback(results);
 });

};
```

Comment: Could you show how you called function payment_info

Comment: Yes will edit question.

Comment: You should pass callback function to your payment_info function. payment_info(paypalT, function(first,paid,state){ }) something like that.

Comment: didn't understand what you mean

Comment: payment_info function have 2 parameters - paypalT and callback, but you didn't pass it to function. Maybe your should do something like that async.apply(payment_info, paypalT, callback)?